# Binding rows of two data frames (merging by column names) with duplicated column names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'd like to bind rows of two df's by column names, if column doesn't exist in 2nd df, first should have NA's. Unfortunately `dplyr::bind_rows` has a problem with duplicated column names. Could you help me how to solve this problem?

What I did so far?

First some reproducible data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df1) <- c('A','A','A','B','C','E')
colnames(df2) <- c('A','B','C')

df1
   A A A B C E
1  0 1 0 1 1 1
2  1 1 1 0 0 0
3  0 0 1 1 0 1
4  0 0 1 0 1 1
5  0 1 0 1 1 0
6  1 0 1 1 1 1
7  0 0 1 1 1 0
8  0 1 0 1 1 0
9  0 1 0 0 1 0
10 1 1 0 1 1 0

df2
   A B C
1  1 1 0
2  0 1 1
3  1 1 0
4  1 0 0
5  0 0 1
6  0 0 1
7  0 1 1
8  0 0 0
9  0 0 1
10 0 1 1
```

What I'd like to get?

```
   A A A B C E
1  0 1 0 1 1 1
2  1 1 1 0 0 0
3  0 0 1 1 0 1
4  0 0 1 0 1 1
5  0 1 0 1 1 0
6  1 0 1 1 1 1
7  0 0 1 1 1 0
8  0 1 0 1 1 0
9  0 1 0 0 1 0
10 1 1 0 1 1 0
11 1 1 1 1 0 NA
12 0 0 0 1 1 NA
13 1 1 1 1 0 NA
14 1 1 1 0 0 NA
15 0 0 0 0 1 NA
16 0 0 0 0 1 NA
17 0 0 0 1 1 NA
18 0 0 0 0 0 NA
19 0 0 0 0 1 NA
20 0 0 0 1 1 NA
```

I decided to use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`, but:

```
result <- bind_rows(mutate_all(df1, as.character), mutate_all(df2, as.character))
Error: Columns `A`, `A` must have unique names
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
cols <- names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]
out <- setDF(rbindlist(list(df1, setNames(df2[cols], cols)), fill = TRUE))
out
#   A A A B C  E
#1  0 1 0 1 1  0
#2  1 1 1 0 1  0
#3  0 1 1 0 1  0
#4  0 0 1 0 1  0
#5  1 0 0 1 0  1
#6  1 1 1 1 0  1
#7  0 0 0 1 0  0
#8  0 0 0 1 0  0
#9  1 1 0 1 0  0
#10 0 1 0 1 1  0
#11 0 0 0 1 1 NA
#12 1 1 1 1 0 NA
#13 0 0 0 0 1 NA
#14 0 0 0 0 1 NA
#15 0 0 0 0 1 NA
#16 1 1 1 1 1 NA
#17 0 0 0 0 0 NA
#18 1 1 1 1 1 NA
#19 0 0 0 1 0 NA
#20 0 0 0 1 1 NA
```

The part `df2[cols]` would result in the following dataframe with unique names

```
#   A A.1 A.2 B C
#1  0   0   0 1 1
#2  1   1   1 1 0
#3  0   0   0 0 1
# ...
```

That's why we call `setNames(df2[cols], cols)` to immediately rename the columns. `setDF` ensures that the result is a `data.frame` and not a `data.table`.

---

Using `bind_rows` you'd end up with only four columns

```
head(bind_rows(df1, setNames(df2[cols], cols)), 3)
#  A B C E
#1 1 1 0 0
#2 0 0 0 0
#3 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Yes, it works great, thank you. Nevertheless, with my bigger data I got `Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)` so I have to find other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be convert the dataframe to list objects and then `cbind` them using `cbind.fill` from `rowr` package with `fill = NA`

```
library(rowr)

new_df <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(mapply(c, as.list(df1),
         as.list(df2)[match(names(df1), names(df2))]), fill = NA))
```

but this loses column names which you can give it back from `df1`.

```
names(new_df) <-  names(df1)
new_df

#   A A A B C  E
#1  0 1 0 0 1  0
#2  0 1 0 0 0  0
#3  0 0 1 1 1  1
#4  0 0 1 0 1  0
#5  1 0 0 0 0  0
#6  0 0 1 0 1  1
#7  0 1 0 0 1  0
#8  0 1 0 0 0  0
#9  0 1 1 0 1  1
#10 1 1 1 0 1  1
#11 0 0 0 1 0 NA
#12 1 1 1 0 0 NA
#13 1 1 1 1 0 NA
#14 0 0 0 1 0 NA
#15 0 0 0 1 1 NA
#16 1 1 1 1 0 NA
#17 0 0 0 1 1 NA
#18 1 1 1 0 0 NA
#19 1 1 1 0 1 NA
#20 1 1 1 0 1 NA
```